# C++ return value from a class-member function

Tags: c++, function, class

I can't understand why a.funct() can be the left operand of the assignment operator even if funct() is not returning a l-value reference.

```
class A
{
public: 
    A funct () {A x; return x;}
};

int main () 
{
    A a,b; a.funct()=b;
}
```

Comment: easy: funct is NOT returning l-value reference (A& instead of A, still that would return address of local variable... still bad)

Comment: What is the declaration of `funct`?

Comment: Why not? It returns an object of class A. Writing `a=b;` is legal and well defined.

Comment: Uh, nevermind.  Browser hiccup ate the declaration of `funct`.

Answer (score 5):

In the auto generated methods for the class, there is

```
A& operator = (const A&);
```

which make `a.funct() = b` legal.

To forbid affectation to rvalue, you may, since C++11, write and implement

```
A& operator = (const A&) &; // Note the last &
```

so assignation would only work for lvalue.

Comment: So the     a.funct()=b;     syntax is right because I can use that operator, but where is the value of b going to be written? Is a.funct() not a temporary variable?

Comment: @Tony It is a temporary variable, but its lifetime lasts for the length of the full-expression it's part of. the contents of `b` will be written to the temporary returned by `funct`, and the temporary will be destroyed at the end of evaluation of the full-expression. As @Jarod42 said, you can explicitly forbid assignment to temporaries (actually rvalues, but temporaries here) by specifically only writing a copy function for lvalues.

Comment: and why is that expression forbidden if the function was defined out of the class like this: int funct () {int x; return x;}
int main () {int b; funct()=b;}

Comment: @Tony because `int` is a fundamental type, and thus `a=b` is not reinterpreted as `a.operator=(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `funct` should return a variable that can be assigned to.

Note that the code in `funct` is very dangerous too if it were to be returned by reference; the local variable `x` will go out of scope once the function ends and the variable returned will cause undefined behaviour as its destructor will have been called.

Comment: It won't as he is returning a copy of (and not a reference or pointer to) `x`

Comment: Yeah, and @12345 said `if it were to be returned by reference`.

Comment: @MatthewRock Take a look on the revision history of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32252928/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. Your code is perfectly valid. 
Try this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>    

class A
{
    std::string m_name;
public:
    A(const std::string& name) :m_name(name) {}

    A funct() { A x("intern"); return x; }

    A& operator=(const A& a)
    {
        m_name += a.m_name;
        return *this;
    }

    void print() { std::cout << m_name << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a("A"), b("B"); (a.funct() = b).print();//prints "internB"
}
```